# Remove JSPM from dependencies

Tags: karma-jasmine, aurelia, jspm

We have developed a single page application using aurelia+type script+jspm.Our purpose is remove the jspm packages from the project. We have using karma framework for unit testing. We have successfully removed all jspm dependency.We have copied the necessary packages from  jspm_packages folder and pasted into new location. The application is working properly. But now when we run the karma unit testing, it cause "System is not defined" error is showing on the console.

The config.js configuration

```
paths: {
    "*": "src/*",
    "github:*": "Scripts/github/*",
    "npm:*": "Scripts/npm/*"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you included system.js properly? Like `<script src="pathToYourNewLocation/system.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes we have also included the new location of system.js, but it is not working

Comment: As @kabaehr mentions, the app can't find System.js at startup. If you can share a bit more details, like for example the index.html including all paths, it might shed some light on the problem.